# Suppress warning Eclipse when developing with Pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, decorator, pydev

I want to suppress Eclipse warnings when defining decorators.

For example:

```
def tool_wrapper(func):
   def inner(self):
      cmd="test"
      cmd+=func(self)
   return inner

@tool_wrapper
def list_peer(self):
   return "testing "
```

I get warning on a decorator definition: 
"Method 'tool_wrapper' should have self as first parameter

I define the decorator inside a class, so this is the only way it's working properly.

Thanks

Comment: You defined a decorator inside a class? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define your decorator outside the class and pass the instance as an argument, it will work just as fine.

```
def tool_wrapper(func):
    def inner(inst):  # inst : instance of the object
        cmd="test"
        cmd+=func(inst)
        return cmd
    return inner


class Test():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @tool_wrapper
    def list_peer(self):
        return "testing "


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Test()
    print t.list_peer()
```

This script prints `testtesting`

Comment: Thanks, it's working just fine! Is it correct python syntax using function outside the class in a module file ?

Comment: I guess so, as long as you make the necessary imports